# Evaluating an 3-d integral

Tags: calculus

[image]

I have not been able to evaluate the integral in part d).

I get that $\nabla^2 G = \delta(\mathbf{x})$ has Fourier transform of $-|\mathbf{k}|^2 G(\mathbf{k})=1$:

$$\implies \begin{align}\displaystyle G &=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int \frac{-1}{|\mathbf{k}|^2}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} d^3\mathbf{k} \\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{-1}{k^2} e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} k^2 \sin\theta\mathrm{d}\phi\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}k
\end{align}$$

However I am unsure as to how to evaluate this especially with regard to how $\mathbf{k} \cdot\mathbf{x}$ should be evaluated.

Comment: Orient the integration variables so that $\vec{x}$ coincides with the $z$ axis of the polar coordinates.

Comment: What gives you the right to do this? Surely $\mathbf{k} \cdot\mathbf{x}=k_1 rsin\theta cos\phi +k_2 sin\theta sin\phi + k_3 r cos \theta$

Comment: who said the spherical coordinates need to be oriented along the *global* $z$ axis? Just say that $\theta$ is the angle between $\bf k$ and $\bf x$ and you are done. It's just a matter of variable substitution, which is completely up to you. Or, looking from a different perspective: the result of the integral is a scalar anyway so rotation of the coordinate frame doesn't have an effect.